# Django CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing

Tags: django, django-csrf

I have an app in Django and React that I need Login and Logout for

I wanna use SessionAuthentication but I get `"detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing."` Error every time I test it on postman

Can you please let me know how to handle login

I also have csrf_exempt on my view but it still requires csrf token

Here is My Login

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
@csrf_exempt
@require_POST
def user_login(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    username = data.get('username', '')
    password = data.get('password', '')
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        session = request.session.session_key
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        user_info = serializer.data

        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Login successful', 'user': user_info, 'session': session})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid credentials'}, status=401)
```

Here is my Logout

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes([SessionAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return Response({"message": "Logout successful"})
```

Here is my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'backend.apps.BackendConfig',
    'frontend.apps.FrontendConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        # ... other renderer classes
    ],
}

SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'

# Set the session timeout (in seconds)
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 60 * 15  # 15 minutes, adjust as needed

# Set the session cookie name
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'myapp_session'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",    
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

ROOT_URLCONF = 'taskify.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```